Using std::vector::insert to string into vector of uint8_t puts random data in it
I'm serializing data into a vector of uint8_t to send it to another module, I have a string that it returned from a function getVal()  and when I do vector.insert() it it shows random vals more into my vector.

std::string getVal() 
{
    std::string x = "564";
    return x ; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<uint8_t> data {0x70}; 

    data.insert(data.end(),getVal().begin(),getVal().end());

    for (auto i:data)
        std::cout << i <<std::endl; 
    
    std::cout<<data.size()<<std::endl;
    std::cout << getVal() <<" ,type: "<< sizeof(getVal()) << ", .size(): "<< getVal().size()<<std::endl; 


    return 0; 
}


Appreciate your help.
The solution was to loop over the string and use .push_back(), but I need to understand why this happened with .insert().

getVal().begin() creates an iterator into a string; getVal.end() creates an iterator into a different string; the two iterators don't point at a valid sequence.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

can you read about Pass parameters by Value vs pass parameters by referece ? i think you will get more insight into why your code doesn't work, specifically getVal return type is causing the issue.

You probably should use std::transform anyway since you are changing data types (at least to indicate intent). And then there is std::back_inserter that you can use instead of push_back

Because getVal Return by value, the two calls will return two different and unrelated std::string objects.
The begin and end iterators of those objects will be related to different objects, and using them together will lead to undefined behavior.
Either you need to create a static string, and return a reference to it. Or you need to store the string that getVal returns and use that object.

That's because you call begin() and end() which return an iterator (basically, a pointer to the underlying array) on a temporary.
You're returning a temporary std::string from the function getVal.
Here is a way you could fix that:
std::string getVal() {
  std::string x = "564";
  return x; // note: Simpler is 'return "564";'
}

int main() {
  std::vector<uint8_t> data { 'p' };
  auto val = getVal(); // OK: Copy of the string.
  data.insert(data.end(), val.begin(), val.end());
}


Using a temporary isn't the problem; using two different temporaries is.

Clear enough, Thanks

Make sure you don't have a temporary string and use, std::transform and std::back_inserter like this:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string getVal() 
{
    std::string x = "564";
    return x ; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<uint8_t> data {0x70}; 
    auto string = getVal();
    std::transform(string.begin(),string.end(), std::back_inserter(data), [](const char c) { return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(c); });

    for (const auto i:data)
        std::cout << i << "\n";

    return 0; 
}


Using a temporary would be okay (although it would require a bit of gymnastics); using two different temporaries is the problem.

@PeteBecker I wanted to avoid said gymnastics ;)  But yes I agree with the two different ones being the real problem in OP's question.

Clear enough, Thanks
